# IBM RAD fails with JVM crash after importing a project into it .shows "jvm terminated exit code 8096"

Tags: jvm, rad

jvm terminated exit code 8096 is shown

here follows my eclipse.ini  coding

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP70\jdk\jre\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Xquickstart
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024ms
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
-Xscmx96m
-Xshareclasses:singleJVM,keep
-Xnolinenumbers
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024M
-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false
-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
```

Answer (score 1):

This behavior might be caused by the incorrect rendering on a small set of Microsoft Windows computers with bad DirectDraw or Direct3D drivers. Hence, the use of `DirectDraw` or `Direct3D` drivers by Java 2D system in Rational Application Developer v7 can cause the crash.

**Note:** This error is not always caused as the result of DirectDraw or Direct3D drivers.

**Resolving the problem**

Consider upgrading to the latest Rational Application Developer v7.0.x release before carrying out the option of disabling Direct3D.

In the case of Rational Application Developer v8.0 or later versions on a Windows 64-bit platform experiencing this JVM error, consult the technote "Internet Explorer v9 or higher is required if the product was installed using the 64-bit Bit Mode option on a 64-bit system". This addresses the jscript.dll error showing in a javacore.

You can also try clearing the temp folder as described in the following forum post. The workaround presented is for Lotus Notes, but may also apply in this case.

WORKAROUND:
To turn off the use of Direct3D in Rational Application Developer v7, you can use the following Java parameter option:

> -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false

If that does not solve the problems, try removing DirectDraw or Direct3D completely using:

> -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true

**Note:** You can put this Java parameter option inside the eclipse.ini in the directory \SDP70\

Open a service request with IBM support if none of the suggestions above have helped to resolve the problem.

Reference [Click Here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21303648)